# How to get the content of a document in documentum

Tags: documentum, dfc, documentum6.5, documentum-dfs, documentum-dfc

I am new to documentum,can anyone suggest me how to get the content of a document in documentum. I am using the following code

```
document = (IDfSysObject) session.getObject(new DfId("some document id"));
document.getContent();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
DfSysObjectException:: THREAD: main; MSG: [DM_SYSOBJECT_E_INVALID_PAGE_NUM]error:  "Invalid page number = 0 for 0000868416 sysobject.  Maximum page count is 0."; ERRORCODE: 100; NEXT: null
at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObjectException.newInvalidPageNumberException(DfSysObjectException.java:47)
at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.ContentManager.verifyPageExists(ContentManager.java:151)
at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.ContentManager.getContentNoPermissionCheck(ContentManager.java:106)
at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.ContentManager.getContent(ContentManager.java:91)
at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.ContentManager.getStream(ContentManager.java:50)
at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.getContentEx3(DfSysObject.java:1952)
at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.getContentEx2(DfSysObject.java:1942)
at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.getContent(DfSysObject.java:1932)
at com.documentum.fc.client.DfDocument___PROXY.getContent(DfDocument___PROXY.java)
```

Can any one please help me with the above error and Is it the right way to get the content of a document with

```
 document.getContent();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the object does not have any content, otherwise getContent() would retrieve it (primary content format and page 0).

Make sure that the object indeed has any content. Make dump of the sysobject and post it here, I will take a look.

Comment: thanks @KarolBe the document was a virtual document which has some components(childs),so we were unable to get the data of the document,now i found that there are many virtual documents in the docbase and i have a requirement to get the metadata of all the childs(current version) of all virtual documents by a single dql query,please can anyone help me